# Assembly code for Neon Intrinsic Version

Tags: android, assembly, android-ndk, neon

I am new to Neon Assembly programming, I have developed a Neon Intrinsic version of video edge detection algorithm, it resulted in gaining 2x performance. Now I would like to try Neon assembly - I would like to view the assembly code generated by compiler for Neon Intrinsic and try my own Neon assembly. My question is how to view the assembly code generated by compiler for Neon Intrinsic optimized code in Android NDK?

When I tried

> objdump -d kalifilters-intrinsics.o
>
> kalifilters-intrinsics.o:     file format elf32-little
>
> objdump: can't disassemble for architecture UNKNOWN!

I am aware of objdump failure since the object file is meant of arm architecture, Kindly let me know arm related objdump tool !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NDK includes architecture-specific objdump binaries:

```
$ find ./ -iname \*objdump\*|grep arm
./toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/arm-linux-android
eabi/bin/objdump.exe
./toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.6/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-and
roideabi-objdump.exe
./toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/arm-linux-android
eabi/bin/objdump.exe
./toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-and
roideabi-objdump.exe
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend IDA Pro for that purpose :

https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/

Just drag the .o / .so file to IDA, and you will get the disassembly in a quite readable format.

There is simply nothing better than that. There's also a Linux version as well as OS X.

Comment: Great that they support so many ARM variants. Evaluation version loaded up my ARMv7 `.so`, no problem.